# Unknown console window

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus

Suddenly I got console window popup in my Windows 10 laptop screen. I was doing no action with my PC and suddenly it appeared. I have noticed in the past console window appearing for half a second and disappearing. Do I have virus? How to correct this?

[image]

Comment: download and update then run the free version of malwarebytes.com

Comment: You most likely have a virus. You will find lots of good advice in the link.